# Identifying MaxSpeed of a Bonded Interface

Tags: rhel, ethernet, bonding

I have configured Ethernet Bonding for our RHEL 6.2 Servers. Bonding is working fine but few confusion for me when I configured MRTG to monitor the bonded interface.

MRTG is showing MaxSpeed of the Bonded Interface to be 1250.0 KBytes/s which comes to be 10 Mbits/s. The MaxSpeed for the Slave interface speed (eth0,eth1) looks fine with 125.0 MBytes/s.

My confusion here is since MRTG is showing MaxSpeed of the bonded interface to be 1250.0 KBytes/s, will it be able to handle traffic beyond 10MBits/s or it is MRTG configuration issue only?

Also, would like to know when monitoring a bonded interface, is it OK to monitor the bonded interface only or need to monitor Slave interface also. Any best practices?

Please find the bonding config pasted below.

$ vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-bond0

```
DEVICE=bond0
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.11.149
NETMASK=255.255.255.192
GATEWAY=192.168.11.130
USERCTL=no
BONDING_OPTS="mode=1 miimon=100"
```

$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
SLAVE=yes
MASTER=bond0
TYPE=Ethernet
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

If any other information is required, please let me know.